# ¿Cómo insertar valores a SQL desde C# con procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo un código en C# que me genera valores para insertar a una tabla en SQL, entonces el código me genera algo así:

`(1,''nombre'',''edad''),(2,''nombre1'',''edad1'')` (uso doble comilla simple)

Mi procedimiento almacenado es algo así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertarValor(@Tabla VARCHAR(MAX),@Valor VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
   DECLARE @SQLString VARCHAR(MAX);
   SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO dbo.'+@Table+' VALUES '+@Value;
   EXEC (@SQLString);
```

Entonces al ejecutar mi aplicación, los valores que generó C# se concatenan, de tal forma las comillas simples dobles indican que será un String. Pero al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado desde C# me salta un error de que la sintaxis de los valores no es correcta, pero si ejecuto el procedimiento almacenado manualmente desde SQL con el comando EXEC, funciona correctamente, será que ExecuteStoreProcedure me elimina las dobles comillas simples?

Este es el código que utilizo para ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado

```
public void InsertarDatosTabla(string company, string tabla, string valores) {
    ParamTable param = new ParamTable(2);
    DataBase db = new DataBase(Helper.getConnection(company));
    param.Add("@Tabla", tabla);
    param.Add("@Valor", valores);
    db.ExecuteStoreProcedure("insertarValor", ref param);
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: En general, es mejor evitar SQL dinámico y el concatenar valores en una cadena SQL.  Es una puerta abierta a muchos problemas. Aunque a primera vista pudiera parecer una buena idea definir un procedimiento almacenado que puede insertar valores en cualquier tabla, esto no es buena práctica. Mejor es usar un SQL parametrizado. O, si es posible, usar algo como Entity Framework para evitar una cantidad de cadenas SQL en tu código.

Comment: Hola que tal, gracias. lo que pasa es que mi aplicación crea tablas dinámicas a partir de un documento en excel, entonces para crear un procedimiento almacenado para cada tabla que se crea sería un lío, por eso mismo uso el SQL dinámico

Comment: @dr4kxn355, ¿y que estas usando para pasar los parámetros y llamar al stored desde C#? mejor etiqueta tu pregunta, si esto es Ado.Net entonces agrega esa etiqueta. No veo tu código C#.

Comment: Acabo de poner el código arriba

Comment: Que clase es `DataBase`? Porque si es la de entity framework, esta no tiene ningun método `ExecuteStoreProcedure`.

Comment: [Este vídeo te mostrará como crear un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server](https://youtu.be/wDCs8OjZevk)

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar comilla simple, porque lo pasas desde c#.
Además veo que el procedimiento almacenado se declara los parametros con un nombre y cuando se hace uso de ellos, se usan otros nombres.

Se declara:

```
@Tabla VARCHAR(MAX),
```

y se usa

```
@Table
```